Could not install gradle into Android studio on Mac
I have lost 4 days.. I am using Mac Os Catalina. I have installed Android studio.
But when i create a new project Build failing always.
getting same error all the time..

Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip'.
Reason: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch

I tried using SDKMan and Terminal is showing gradle -version 8.9
Which Gradle command shows path => /Users/rushikant/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin/gradle
If i goes to Android studio preferences->Build Tools->Gradle and Changes gradle user home to above then also next time it automatically path shows => /Users/rushikant/.gradle
